# combination between axis and multi figures

Tags: diagrams

how can I combine a figure of multi images with two axis(x and y)axis like the following attached photo[image: the relationship between the time and quantity of different materials]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `tikz` `matrix` library.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\newcommand{\graphics}[1]{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{#1}}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    mygrid/.style={matrix of nodes,
       row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
       nodes={minimum size=1cm}, nodes in empty cells},
]

\matrix (m) [mygrid]
{
|[shift={(-2mm,6mm)}]|100 & \graphics{example-image}&\graphics{example-image-a}&\graphics{example-image-a}&\graphics{example-image-c}\\
|[shift={(-2mm,6mm)}]|200 & \graphics{example-image}&\graphics{example-image-a}&\graphics{example-image-a}&\graphics{example-image-c}\\
|[shift={(-2mm,6mm)}]|300 & \graphics{example-image}&\graphics{example-image-a}&\graphics{example-image-a}&\graphics{example-image-c}\\
|[shift={(-2mm,6mm)}]|400 & \graphics{example-image}&\graphics{example-image-a}&\graphics{example-image-a}&\graphics{example-image-c}\\
& 0:100 & 25:75 & 50:50 & 75:75 \\
};

\draw[thick,-latex] ([shift={(-2mm,-2mm)}]m-4-2.south west) --
         ([shift={(5mm,-2mm)}]m-4-5.south east)
               node[pos=0.5,below=7mm]{PLGA: Myristic Acid Ratio};
\draw[thick,-latex] ([shift={(-2mm,-2mm)}]m-4-2.south west) --
         ([shift={(-2mm,5mm)}]m-1-2.north west)
               node[pos=0.5,left=10mm,rotate=90,anchor=center]{Magnification};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: that's very nice, but how can I label the y axis like we found in x axis, I mean how can I add the (number or name )each magnification to this figure?????

Comment: @WathiqZayed Add one extra column at the beginning like I did for x label (a row is added there.)

Comment: sorry but I tried to add but I couldnt get the required

Comment: @WathiqZayed Please don't forget to upvote and accept the answers. For details please see: [How do you accept an answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer)

Comment: I tried but I couldnt do that

Comment: @WathiqZayed You are welcome :) Happy to help.

Comment: I hope you are fine, I would like to ask you about the following figure.. how can I create like that one? and the grphs were plotted by r-studio.. I mean can i re plot these figures using latex and r-studio? or i can deal with them as a picture? thanks

Comment: @WathiqZayed I am fine thank you. Where is the figure?

Comment: [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/frGgw.png

Comment: @WathiqZayed You can simply include it using `\includegraphics`. It looks good. Why do you want to redraw?

Comment: I plotted it using r- studio but I need to import this figure in my lated document ... so when I inserted it as a picture I couldnt get high resolution figure..so I tried to plot it using r-stodio and latex ...but the problem I couldnt understand how to use them togather

Comment: @WathiqZayed Export that picture from r studio as `figure.pdf` (say) and in latex document use `\includegraphics[width=4cm]{figure}` This needs `\usepackage{graphicx}` and adjust the `width`  suitably.

Comment: Hi Kumar, I hope you are fine. I have just wanted to ask you about how can I insert a figure or picture on another picture?

Comment: @WathiqZayed Sorry for the late response. Search `writing on image` in this site, you will find beautiful answers. :)